# Adding transparency to grayscale image using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, transparency-opacity

I have some binary mask image with 255 and 0 values and I want 0 values become transparent.

How can I do this?

---

Seems it work, but I'm not sure if it the best method:

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -of PNG src.png dst.png
```

Comment: `gdal_translate` with `a_nodata` is the best way.

Comment: @LoganByers, please expand your comment into an answer explaining why `a_nodata` is the best way.